# FCM with PHP not showing additonalData in console

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm send push notifications using php, what I've realise is the push notification comes to the phone, but fails to send the additional data I add to the script for example page etc.

```
<?php

$url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$token = 'device_id here';
$serverKey = 'AIzaSxxxbAGLyxxxx';
$title = "New Message";
$body = 'Hello there';
$notification = array('title' =>$title , 'message' => $body,'priority'=>'high','badge'=>'1','notId'=>''.time(), 'id' => '33','page' => 'news');
$arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification);
$json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. $serverKey;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
//Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
//Close request
if ($response === FALSE) {
die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to add custom data fields to a `Notification` message. `Notification` messages only allow certain fields. If you want to send custom data then you need to make your message a `Data` message or a `Notification` message with data payload.

From the FCM docs a combination `Notification` message with data payload for android could look like this:

```
{
  "to":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "notification":{
      "title":"New Message",
      "body":"Hello there"
    },
    "data" : {
      "notId" : 201801,
      "id" : 33,
      "page" : "news",
    }
}
```

Make these changes to the message structure:

```
$notification = array('title' =>$title , 'message' => $body);
$data = array('notId'=>''.time(), 'id' => '33','page' => 'news');
$arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification, 'data' => $data);
```

You will need to change your android code to accommodate the `data` field and parse the data accordingly.

Please read the FCM documentation carefully is see which ramifications this change can have on your project. Most importantly, how `data` messages are handled when you app is in the background!